# Custom spacing between x axis labels in ggplot

Tags: r

I have a df:

```
   Year          Ratio       N    Mean        sd        se        ci
97  1867 TILLBANK...PLACTILL 2  3.861999  4.082170  2.886530  36.67685
98  1867   TILLOBL..PLACTILL 2 21.848833 17.859532 12.628596 160.46153
99  1867   TILLLOAN.PLACTILL 2 54.197044 23.309360 16.482207 209.42629
100 1867   TILLEQUI.PLACTILL 2  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000   0.00000
101 1867   TILLCONT.PLACTILL 2  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000   0.00000
102 1867   TILLRECI.PLACTILL 2 10.772286  5.110514  3.613679  45.91615


str(df) :

     'data.frame':  1152 obs. of  7 variables:
 $ Year : Factor w/ 156 levels "1855","1856",..: 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 14 14 ...
 $ Ratio: Factor w/ 8 levels "TILLBANK...PLACTILL",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 1 2 ...
 $ N    : num  2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ Mean : num  3.86 21.85 54.2 0 0 ...
 $ sd   : num  4.08 17.86 23.31 0 0 ...
 $ se   : num  2.89 12.63 16.48 0 0 ...
 $ ci   : num  36.7 160.5 209.4 0 0 ...
```

**1)** I am doing a `ggplot`:

```
qqs<-ggplot(dfccomp, aes(x=Year, y=sd,colour=Ratio))+geom_point()+
    facet_grid(Ratio~.)+
    theme(axis.text.x  = element_text(angle=-90, hjust=0.5, size=11,colour="black"))
```

This plot works with `geom_point()` but now with `geom_line()`. If I use `geom_point()` I then get very messy x-axis with all the years (from 1867 to 2010): 
[image]

And if I use `geom_line()`,which does not work, I get:
[image]

So, I wonder how it is possible to only pick some certain years to be present on the x axis?

**2)** The other strange thing that I dont understand is if I convert the `df$Year` above to numeric,

```
df$Year=as.numeric(as.character(df$Year))
```

Plot is then:
[image]

Now, only 3 years are present on the x-axis. Which is better but still not what I want...

why does both `geom_point()` and `geom_line()` works?

Updated:
On the answer below I read that "Year is a factor and as such ggplot() will interpret that accordingly and produce a dotplot. The reason geom_line() doesn't do anything as this geom doesn't make sense for the data supplied; the factor nature indicates to ggplot() that the x-axis is not continuous and there is nothing to draw between points on that axis, hence no lines.".

But I have a different plot where `geom_line()` works with a factor. Why is it so?

```
qq<-ggplot(df, aes(x=Year, y=Mean,colour=Ratio)) + 
    geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=Mean-sd, ymax=Mean+sd), colour="black", width=.1, position=position_dodge(.1)) +
    geom_line(position=position_dodge(.1)) +
    geom_point(position=position_dodge(.1), size=3, shape=21, fill="white") + # 21 is filled circle
    xlab("Year") +
    ylab("Mean (%)")+ggtitle("Ratios")+facet_grid(Ratio~.)+theme(axis.text.x  = element_text(angle=-90, hjust=0.5, size=11,colour="black"))
```

The picture:
[image]

Comment: Can you please update your question so that we can "haz data" or at least a figure? I suspect, though, that you need to introduce `group` variable into your `aes` call.

Comment: Of course:) I find it very strange why both geom_line() and geom_point() work when the Year is numeric. But I mostly wonder how I can adjust the x axis scale, so the scale is not so messy as in the top 2 pictures. Best Regards!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use `Year` as factor, `ggplot` will print a label for every factor level. You can see this in your first two plots.

If you use `Year` as numeric variable, `ggplot` will automatically select a subset of the values for the labels of the x-axis. In your third plot, the distance between two breaks is 100.

You can manually specify where to do you want the break points on the x-axis with `scale_x_continuous` and the argument `breaks`. In the example below, a the distance between the breaks is 20. Play around with the code to find the desired plot.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=as.numeric(as.character(Year)), y=sd, colour=Ratio)) +
geom_point() +
facet_grid(Ratio~.) +
theme(axis.text.x  = element_text(angle=-90, hjust=0.5, size=11,colour="black")) +
scale_x_continuous(breaks = as.numeric(levels(df$Year))[c(TRUE, rep(FALSE, 19))])
```

Comment: Thanks Sven! Did look up scale_x_continuous actually, but could manage to get it correctly:) Thanks again for the superb answer!!

Answer (score 6):

`Year` is a factor and as such `ggplot()` will interpret that accordingly and produce a dotplot. The reason `geom_line()` doesn't do anything as this geom doesn't make sense for the data supplied; the factor nature indicates to `ggplot()` that the x-axis is not continuous and there is nothing to draw between points on that axis, hence no lines.

That this is the case is clearly shown by the figure you get with `geom_line()` after converting `Year` to a numeric variable. Now `ggplot()`, following its grammar, produces a line chart for the continuous x-axis data.

So now your question boils down to controlling the scale on the x-axis (scale is what `ggplot()` calls the axis). I see two options;

1. Provide your own scale using `scale_x_continous()` as documented [here](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/scale_continuous.html)
2. Convert your `Year` numeric data to a `Date` object and let `ggplot()` handle the scale or customise it via `scale_x_date()`, as documented and illustrated [here](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/scale_date.html)

To convert to a `Date` object you could do something like this:

```
dfccomp <- transform(dfccomp,
                     Year = as.Date(paste(Year, "01", "01", sep = "-")))
```

alter the two `"01"`s to be whatever month (the first `"01"`) or day of month you want, but whatever you choose it is in effect arbitrary and not required; that data points will be 1 year apart.

You can then use the `minor_breaks` argument in `scale_x_date()` to control how many or where minor ticks are shown, plus the `breaks` argument to set which years are shown. I suggest you don't show all years otherwise the resulting plot will be a mess. You also don;t need each year as a minor break as agin the grid lines will just swamp the plot.

Comment: You were a few seconds faster.

Comment: Thanks Gavin! Great answer too! But see my update of the question, geom_line() works even if Year is a factor...

Comment: @user1665355 It is impossible to tell what is going on there, the figure is too reproduced small to see. I presume because you a dodging a small amount this is allowing a line to be drawn. You shouldn't need tricks like this to get round the way your data are formatted. You should format the data into the correct types so that ggplot produces the correct graphic. The new figure you show is a bit of a mess with all the background grid lines.

Comment: Of course, I just wanted to understand why it works:) But thanks a lot for the superb answer! R has quiet a steep learning curve and thanks to you guys it gets a little less steep for us other users:)

Comment: Without your data I can't check but is it actually working? Do you get a line if you stop after the `geom_line()` call and don't add anything  other layers? Without your data I can't run this myself and your figure shows the result *after* adding the extra layers. If it does show something then it is the dodging that is allowing some of the line to be drawn, but I doubt it is correct.

Comment: No I dont get a line there...Just errorbars, so I think i will just remember to use correct data formats in the future:)

Comment: Thanks for the update; I was a little surprised when you said it worked in your updated example. Glad you found [so] useful today.